# How can I get the ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle of Alamofire in Unit Testing case?

Tags: swift, testing, server, alamofire

I use Alamofire framework with a project testing.

In a simple project, I can get the list of certificat server by calling ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle of Alamofire.

But how can I do that in project testing? The ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle always return me no certificate.